# XAMPP server crash in regular interval with the MSVCR110.dll error

Tags: apache, visual-c++, crash, xampp, server

**Issue:**
XAMPP Server crash in regular interval with the MSVCR110.dll error.

**Our analysis:**

1. We upgrade the RAM size from 8 GB to 64GB
2. Stops few background process to reduce the load in CPU.
3. Some solution suggested to install below software, we did. But still no result.
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#
4. Lastly we reinstall fresh XAMPP tool to the server. No luck yet.

We think that some expert help requires to overcome this issue.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have had just the same issue!
The only solution that has solved my case is to download and put the dll in the place from here http://fix4dll.com/Msvcr110_dll
Hope this helps!